# Add delay between characters printed to RTB

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a little game where i have a console simulated using an RTB. The game itself runs LUA scripts which call an API function for outputting to the console. This API then fires an event (using caliburn micro) which is picked up by the console class and the message is appended to the RTB.

I'm now wanting to have the ability to add a small delay between each character in the message, giving it a little more effect. Unfortunately I've hit somewhat of a brick wall with this. While i can easily add a delay between the characters using a second thread and sleep, or timers. I run into the problem that if the scripts sends two messages to the console the second is being processed at the same time as the delayed one, as such the text comes out garbled.

What i'm after is a way to have a small delay between characters being printed in a message, but also wait until it's finished before processing subsequent calls to output to the console.

Threading is something I've used only at a basic level in reality. I think i understand the basic concepts. But this one is giving me some issues. If i try waiting for the delay thread to complete it blocks the main thread and nothing is output (hence the entire program hangs forever)

Hopefully i've explained this well enough. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at Thread.Sleep & lock() statement - also show us code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you want to use here is a queue, parralelQueue if you don't feel like locking.

The event handler will just add the message to the queue and a separate process will read one and slowly print it for as long as there are items in the queue. Below is an example of how to do this using parralelQueue.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

ConcurrentQueue<string> MessageQueue;
ManualResetEventSlim queRefilled = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
bool writerStopper;
Task messageWriter;

private void MessageDispatcher() //this is going to be the writing thread
{
    while (!writerStopper)
    {
        if(MessageQueue.Count ==0)
        {
            //loop every 200 seconds to check the writerStopper
            if (!queRefilled.Wait(200)) //wait until we know that a message has been added, this was done to minimize latency.
                continue;
            queRefilled.Reset();
            continue;
        }
        string message;
        if (MessageQueue.TryDequeue(out message))
            yourWriteMethod(message); //here you can call your existing writer
    }
}
//call this to add a message to the screen
public void QueueToScreen(string message)
{
    MessageQueue.Enqueue(message);
    queRefilled.Set(); //set the flag so that the writer knows that there are messages
}

public void start()
{
    MessageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    writerStopper = false;
    messageWriter = new Task(MessageDispatcher);
    messageWriter.Start();
}

    public void stop() 
{
   writerStopper = true;
   MessageQueue = null;
}
```

This code try's to minimize latency with the ManualResetEventSlim. You could also just use thread.sleep but then it would get slightly less responsive. Also I ignored cancellationTokens because lazy. If you never want to stop the tread before the main app you can just use a while(true) and queRefilled.Wait() which will block indefinitely;

Comment: This worked like a charm. Id been working on some form a queue system but always stumbled when it came to the locking stuff. This solve that nicely. Thanks!